# k-valued point of $\mathbb{P}_k^n $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ k $ be a field. A k-valued point of $\mathbb{P}_k^n $ is define to be a scheme morphism
$$ \operatorname{Spec}k \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$$
Is this the same as just specifying a maximal homogeneous ideal of $k[x_ 0,…,x_n] $? If so, is such an ideal always generated by n linear homogeneous polynomials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Stacks Project Lemma 01NA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01NA), morphisms from $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ to $\operatorname{Proj}k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ correspond to strict equivalences (see the discussions before the cited lemma) of pairs of an invertible $k$-module $\mathcal L$ and a graded ring morphism $\psi:k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\rightarrow\Gamma_*(\operatorname{Spec}k,\mathcal L)$ such that $\mathcal L$ is generated by the global sections $\psi(f)$ for $f\in k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ of degree $1$.

Since an invertible $k$-module is isomorphic to $k$, a $k$-point is determined by a morphism $\psi:k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\rightarrow\Gamma_*(\operatorname{Spec}k,k)$ such that $\psi(x_i)$ is not all $0$ for every $i=0,\ldots,n$. Since $\psi$ is a graded ring homomorphism, its kernel $K$ is a homogeneous ideal of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$. Since $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/K\cong k$, $K$ is a maximal ideal.

But not every maximal ideal corresponds to a $k$-valued point: only those with residue field $k$. If $k$ is algebraically closed, then indeed $k$-valued points are the same as a maximal homogeneous ideals of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$.

**Remark:**

There are definitely easier ways of showing this, but maybe this can be useful.

**Edit:**

As to the added question whether such a maximal homogeneous ideal is generated by $n$ linear homogeneous ideals, consider an index $i_0$ such that $\psi(x_{i_0})\ne0$. Let $a_i$ denote the image of $x_i$ in $k$ under $\psi$. Then we can show that the kernel $K$ is generated by $X_i-(a_i/a_{i_0})X_{i_0}$, where $i\ne i_0$, which is left as an exercise. ;P

> A reference for the statement in the edit is [this stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926348/).

---

If there are any errors, please point it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow I thought for sure the answer to the second question was no. What an interesting contrast to the affine case!

Comment: We can also cover $\mathbb P_k^n$ by affine opens, each of the form $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Then a point lies in one of the covers. So it corresponds to a maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,,x_n]$ with residue field $k$. Then it is of the form $(x_i-a_i)$. After homogenization, it is of the described form above.

Comment: ohhh sorry i was thinking k points of affine scheme just meant closed points, but its stronger. so not such a contrast

Comment: just for my future reference, i note that the post you linked to assumes k algebraically closed. also thanks!